# How to find the position of point on a plane, given the ORDER/Ranking of the distances from other known points (but not the distances)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am playing with IP's (unique identifier of a computer network) and I can send a message from my IP to another IP and calculate how long does it take to get an answer back from it (what is called "ping") - sort of what you would do with a radar/sonar.

Now, I can "ping" the same IP from different IP's spread around the world and get the results (in miliseconds) and use it as a proxy for distance.However, I cannot rely entirely on the ping to calculate the distance, as there are other factors that affect the measure, so using the ping as a ratio for the distances wouldn't be very accurate.

Still, I believe with enough data points (I have around 80) and the ranking/order of these points, I could get a very good idea of where this point lies on.

Inb4: I am aware that there are other better methods to discover an IP's location. I am just curious about how one would do it using just this information.

**Example:**
The table below shows the ranking of the distances between a given unknown geolocation point and other known locations around the Globe (the ping is the average of many attempts):

Ranking |       City                    |   Ping (ms);

1       |   United States - S. Antonio  |   51.068;

2       |   United States - Seattle     |   71.961;

3       |   Denmark - Copenhagen        |   86.893;

4       |   Italy - Milan               |   91.440;

5       |   Portugal - Lisbon           |   100.414;

6       |   Poland - Warsaw             |   100.522;

7       |   Lithuania - Vilnius         |   104.825;

8       |   Russian Federation - Moscow |   116.660;

9       |   Israel - Kiryat-Matalon     |   136.277;

10      |   Hungary - Budapest          |   136.810;

Can I find the location of this IP? (the IP used is of one of Google's servers: 72.14.255.255)